# how to update kivy's dialog text

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to change the dialog text according to the value of the variable, but the dialog text doesn't update..

mycode:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_alert_dialog()
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    var1="var1 value is 10"

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
        

    def show_alert_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                text=self.var1,
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="DISCARD", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,on_release= self.dialog_close
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def dialog_close(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)
        print(self.var1)
        self.var1="var1 value is 30"

Example().run()
```

On my console the variable changes value, but the dialog continues with the previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var1` is not linked to the text value, you just copied the value of the var, not the reference so when you change your var, it won't change your text. Here is how you can change your text.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_alert_dialog()
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    var1 = "var1 value is 10"

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_alert_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                text=self.var1,
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="DISCARD", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.dialog_close
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def dialog_close(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)
        print(self.var1)
        self.var1 = "var1 value is 30"
        self.dialog.text = self.var1


Example().run()
```

Comment: this makes sense, thank you very much for the answer ^^